# NetBeans Doesn't Display Chinese Content

Tags: php, netbeans

Good day,

My dev pc env like this,
Win11 and NetBeans16 installed. I am dev PHP Lang now.

When I opened an existing source code folder and I found these Chinese content can't display normally.( Pls see screen capture posted as below)

I already tried several methods as below,

1. I configured the NetBeans Project Encoding to UTF-8; // doesn't work
2. I tried to type simple Chinese content in the IDE directly; // Same issue
3. I googled and modified the 'netbeans.conf' file and added the
   **-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8**
   at the end of **netbeans_default_options="** , and then I restarted my NetBeans or enen I reboot my win OS. The problem is still can't resolve.

BTW,
I could view the Chinese content in Visula Studio Code via my PC.
And I configured my DB encode to UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4).

Thks for your suggestions in advance.

[image: 01.png]

Comment: Can you update your question with some of the Chinese text that cannot be rendered in the NetBeans edit window so that others can attempt to reproduce your problem? Also, what font are you using in NetBeans (**Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > Font**), and what is your operating system? And if you are using Windows, what is your locale?

Comment: @skomisa, I changed the config in **Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > Font** from 'MS Reference Sans Serif 18' to 'Microsoft YaHei UI', it works now. Thanks for you guide above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed Skomisa's suggestion. I solved the issue as below,
I must choose one font that support Chinese character and then I could render it in NetBeans edit window.(as I commented above)

See the result attached.
[image: 01.png]